# Extending continuous functions with compact domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" there is a proposition:

If $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and $f:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous, then there exists a continuous map $\bar{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\bar{f}=f$ on $K$.

The proof is constructive and cites the Weierstrass $M$-test:

[image]

It is not clear to me what is happening here. How is $v_k(x)f(s_k)$ meant to be bounded so that the $M$-test can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually confused about how to control the growth of $\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}$ in order to bound $\frac{2^{-k}u_{s_k}(x)f(s_k)}{\sigma(x)}$, but I now realize that since

$$\bar{f}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma(x)} \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} u_{s_k}(x)f(s_k)$$

we only need to show that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} u_{s_k}(x)f(s_k)$ converges uniformly; this would imply the continuity of the quotient because $\sigma(x)$ is never zero.